# SQL & Java Error with using SQL characters

Tags: java, mysql, sql, syntax

I have a problem with SQL that I can't seem to get rid of. The problem is when special characters are being used that sql statements itself use, it does not like it at all. I tried many things and could not find a answer.

The error is caused by using the ' character in the text that is being put into the SQL table.

```
NobleCore.getSQLStaticly().updateSQL("INSERT INTO Punishment (`ID`, `UUID`, `PlayerName`, `StaffName`, `Sev`, `pType`, `Reason`, `Activated`, `Ends`, `Active`, `RemoveReason`, `RemovedBy`) VALUES (NULL, '" + playerUUID + "', '" + player + "', '" + staffName + "' , '" + severity + "', '" + pType +"', '" + reason + "', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'" + end + "', '1', NULL, NULL );");
```

As you can see when it adds the '" + reason + "' the string from the method parameter it will error out causing a syntax exception because it contains the ' character. How can I get it to add this character so it knows it's part of the string and not to be used in the statement.

```
[17:28:29] [Server thread/WARN]: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ']', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'2015-02-26 17:58:29.708', '1', NULL, NULL )' at line 1
```

If you need any other code, let me know but I don't see how it will help :P

Comment: You should sanitize/escape the data in java before saving.

Comment: What is the value of the variable reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual practice in this case is to use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) rather than building a statement dynamically from scratch.

In a `PreparedStatement`, you put question marks where the values should go, and then you use various `setXXX` methods to fill them up with values. The `setString()` method, for example, escapes the quotes in the given value appropriately for the database in question (that is, based on the JDBC driver, there may be different ways of escaping quotes, and JDBC does this for you automatically).

If you insist on building the query yourself, the standard way to escape quotes in SQL is to double them. For example, if your value is `Sean O'Connor`, the appropriate quoted value is `Sean O''Connor`. It's easy to write a method to double each single quote in the string.

But again, I would recommend trusting the authors of your JDBC driver for this and using a `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: Alright thanks man. Great clean explanation! Ill look into using prepared statements instead.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a character within the variable `reason` which is rendering your SQL invalid. Use a prepared statement to save the values instead. BTW `NULL` values can be omitted from the query